# wp form submit error show 404 page content

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme for a website. Problem is that when I submit form this goes to correct url but shows 404 page content always. I have verifieds .htaccess, delete all posts because I am using page as CMS. Also try to solve using wp_options rewrite_rules but not successful. I also check functions.php but didn't find any special code for form submit.

Like in my local machine If I directly write url in browser its working. However when I submit using form page not showing and shows 404 page content.

I use  krumo debug plugin and its showing wrong get values for name and postTYpe variables use internally by wp but correct pagename.

Does anyone suggest why I am having this problem in wp although I am using latest wp.

Thank You.

Comment: I have solved this. This is due to name input box that I am using on forms. Its really unexpected for me.. I have change the name input box to student_name and its working. What I understand wordpress use name for finding the pagename from database and its conflicting but I think this should change in wp structure to solve this problem... Anyways thank you.

Comment: You should answer your own question thus removing this from the "Unaswered" section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this. This is due to name input box that I am using on forms. Its really unexpected for me.. I have change the name input box to student_name and its working. What I understand wordpress use name for finding the pagename from database and its conflicting but I think this should change in wp structure to solve this problem...

Comment: You need to click the big ✔ next to the answer that solves the question so everyone knows what worked.